# How can a web page read the file structure of a given directory?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have a directory containing several files, and the directory is part of a web app on the server side. I also have a HTML page, on which I want to populate the names of the files within that directory.

I don't need to access the content of these files, but only list their names on the page upon each page load.

Is this something that can be done by Javascript or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript (running on the client) can make HTTP requests to the server. It can't read the filesystem directly.

The server can generate a listing of files in whatever data format you like, and include it in an HTTP response. Most webservers will, by default, generate such a listing in HTML format for any directory under the webroot that does not have an index file. This isn't the nicest of formats to parse though.

You would probably be better off using a server side language for this.

If you want to load the data via client side JavaScript, you can have that language output the data in JSON format (or another easily parsable format).

If you don't need to load it dynamically in the middle of a page view, then you can just inject it directly into your page template using the server side language.

The server side language can be pretty much any programming language under the sun, including JavaScript, in which case you may want to use the [file system module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).